# Returning a std::vector - right approach

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to create a class method that will return a std::vector, and am a bit confused about the best way to do this.

The approach I've used is to define the following method:

```
std::vector<double>* GetBins(void);
```

and in the method, allocate a new std::vector, which I fill with data. I'm returning a pointer to this ie.

```
std::vector<double>* Frequency::GetBins(void) {
    std::vector<double> *rtnVec = new std::vector<double>();
    for (_itMap = _mapFreq.begin(); _itMap != _mapFreq.end(); _itMap++ ) {
        rtnVec->push_back((*_itMap).first);
    }
    return rtnVec;
 }
```

(_itMap is a class-defined iterator).

In my main.cpp, I've done the following:

```
 std::vector<double>* myBins;
 myBins = myFreq3->GetBins();
 delete myBins;
```

I know with this approach, I'm going to get a dangling pointer unless I delete the pointer in the main.cpp code, so it's already a bit 'dangerous'. What's the best way to return a new std::vector from a class method?

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: Why do you need to return anything? Create a `BinsProcessor` interface and ask the `Frequency` to process the bins with your `CustomBinsProcessor`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way is to return by value:

```
std::vector<double> Frequency::GetBins() {
    std::vector<double> rtnVec;
    rtnVec.reserve(_mapFreq.size()); // reserve enough size, no reallocations
    for (_itMap = _mapFreq.begin(); _itMap != _mapFreq.end(); ++_itMap ) {
        rtnVec.push_back(_itMap->first);
    }
    return rtnVec;
}
```

Then you'd use the function like this:

```
std::vector<double> myBins = myFreq3->GetBins();
// no need for delete!
```

The compiler will probably use [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and perform no copies. If you're using C++11, then move semantics will ensure that no copies are performed.

Comment: Or `for (auto&& elem: _mapFreq) { rtnVec.push_back(elem.first); }`

Comment: @MSalters yes, that's a better way to iterate the map. However, OP is asking specifically about return semantics, and using a range-based for loop makes no difference here.

Comment: Fair point. Thinking about it, I'd also add a `rtnVec.reserve(_mapFreq.size())`. Again, doesn't affect the return type directly, but it does eliminate some of the copying you'd incur while filling `rtnVec`.

Comment: Another option is to return const reference (const std::vector<double>&), if he just wants to provide access without creating a vector.

Comment: @BЈовић he wants to create and return a vector, hence my answer. Returning const references would be used under other circumstances.

Comment: Yep MSalters, unncessary copying was something I was looking to avoid.  BЈовић - thanks the reference concept seems a bit more efficient.

Comment: For an explicit for iteration loop, `++_itMap` should be used instead of `_itMap++`; I know it's not the core of the question, but it's important to post quality correct code.

Comment: @Pete855217 note that returning a const reference in that example will trigger undefined behaviour if you try to access the vector from outside the function. Just return by value as shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks mfontanini - I suspected that might be a risk with this approach, and thanks Mr.C64 - as I understand it the iterator must be advanced first in this type of loop construct. Could it have caused problems the other way - I didn't notice any, but that's of course not to say they weren't hiding away there!

Comment: @Pete855217 using a postfix increment(X++) is perfectly valid as well. However, using a prefix increment(++X) avoids making an extra copy of the iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Return by value

```
std::vector<double> Frequency::GetBins(void) {
    std::vector<double> rtnVec;

    // ...

    return rtnVec;
 }
```

However if you want return by pointer, you can use smart pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>> Frequency::GetBins(void) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>> rtnVec(new std::vector<double>());

    //...

    return rtnVec;
 }
```

Comment: Unless move semantics are used, returning by value will cause a deep copy, which is far from optimal.

Comment: @ddriver In both the OP's design, and in this post, both `RVO` will occur implicitly, and copy elision should occur at the calling site.  In C++11, close variants of their code will either continue to `RVO`, or will implicitly `move`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid copies/ dangling pointers/..., another way is simply to pass your `std::vector` by reference to the method:

```
void Frequency::GetBins( std::vector<double>& bins ) {
    for (_itMap = _mapFreq.begin(); _itMap != _mapFreq.end(); _itMap++ ) {
        bins->push_back((*_itMap).first);
    }
 }
```

You just need then to define it before:

```
 std::vector<double> myBins;
 myFreq3->GetBins(myBins);
```